# Прилагательное к "гордость"

Tags: словообразование

У слова "гордость" есть (среди прочих) значение "предмет гордости".

> 4. кого или чья. О том, кем (чем) гордятся. Эти музыканты - слава и г. нашей страны. Ты моя
>    радость, моя г.! Она была красой и гордостью семьи.

(БТС Кузнецова)

Как образовать от этого значения прилагательное, а еще лучше - наречие?

(++) ====

Обсуждение в комментариях заставляет меня сделать уточнение.
Мне не нужна философия и разговоры о глаголах.
Мне нужно
образовать прилагательное с подходящим значением.  От этого корня - или от другого - не важно. Будет оно причастием или прилагательным - тоже не проблема.

По схеме.

Предмет восхищения - восхитительный.
Предмет изумления - изумительный.
Предмет обожания - обожаемый.
Предмет возмущения - возмутительный.
Предмет жалости, сожаления - жалкий, жалостливый.
Предмет волнений - волнительный.

(везде есть пусть не точное, но хотя бы близкое значение)

И только два случая ставят меня в тупик.

Предмет гордости-?
Предмет преклонения -?

Причем с преклонением я еще могу смириться ("преклонябельный") - тут само значение несколько надумано. Но гордость-то в этом значении в словарях присутствует!

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118514/discussion-on-question-by-behemothus---).

Comment: Насчет двух случаев -- их намного больше на самом деле: улыбка, толпа, суета, издевание, нрав, итд... Впрочем, по методу shampar'a получаем: Улыбкоприносящий, суетувселяющий, нравопроизводящий итд...

Answer (score 3):

В словаре Г. Дьяченко есть слово *гордоносный* (http://www.slavdict.ru/_0128.htm) — производящий, вселяющий гордость. Оно значится и у В. Даля. В общем ряду подобных по смыслу слов оно имеет несколько иную окраску, не несущую печать дурного воспитания: спесивости, чванства и пр. Второй корень сближает его с другими, по смыслу — благоприобретёнными, такими как *знаменосный*, *оскароносный* и пр., обозначающими символы как сути предмета гордости.

Из примеров употребления встретились только эти:

> "Аэлита" сейчас находится в частной коллекции в Англии. Её милый,
> слегка гордоносный, величественный, но оставшийся нежным и прекрасным
> образ не оставил равнодушным английского коллекционера. / Ю.Токарь

> ... девочка, которая в школе училась на тройбаны, временами на твердую
> четверку (это такая гордоносная, в устной форме, медаль от учителя). / Instagram posts

Comment: Это хорошо. По смыслу. Вопрос только в том, как с использованием этого слова сказать "я сделал работу, которой могу гордиться". .

Comment: И, кстати, а что за упоминаемый ряд синонимов?

Comment: Я сделал гордоносную для меня работу. Я сделал знаменательную для меня работу.

Comment: @user190920 *Я сделал гордоносную для меня работу* - это разве что для эпатажа почтеннейшей публики. *Я сделал знаменательную для меня работу* - а это вообще гвоздь не от той стены. Во-первых, значение очень далекое, во-вторых я не об этом спрашивал: *как **с использованием этого слова** сказать...*

Comment: @behemothus, не ряд синонимов, а  «В общем ряду подобных по смыслу слов...» оно значится среди слов одного корня у В. Даля: https://gufo.me/dict/dal/%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D1%8B%D0%B9. Насчёт эпатажа: вообще публично заявлять о восторге от дел рук своих — акт смелый, если не безумный. Верно выбранные время и место могут сыграть решающую роль. А потом (как там у В.В., «Подняться по крутой спортивной лестнице мне помогли...») всегда полезно рассматривать удачу как общую.

Comment: За ссылку - спасибо. вопрос о том, чем "подобные по смыслу слова" отличаются от "синонимов" выносим за скобки. А насчет "публично заявлять о восторге" - это вообще не ко мне. Замените на "он сделал работу, которой можно гордиться". Эпатаж не в том, что кто-то заявляет о предмете своей гордости (что, конечно, может быть по-разному оценено), а в том, что "гордоносный" тут совершенно не к месту в силу своей окраски (напущенности, что ли)....

Comment: Оба примера из ответа (на мой взгляд) говорят об обратном: хочу и не могу ощутить долю напыщенности. Всё вполне органично, хотя первый пассаж именно от лица автора.